# How to read the content in a azure blob using azure function app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I want to trigger the function app when a file is uploaded into the container and read the content in the file. I'm able to trigger the function app. But when i use Openread to read the content in the file i'm getting reference not found error. Below is the code which I have used to read the file and the binding.

```
#r "System.IO";

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Xml;

using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;

public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log, string 
inputBlob)
{
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: 
    {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputBlob.OpenRead())
    {
        String oldContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Bindings

```
{
    "bindings": [{
            "name": "myBlob",
            "type": "blobTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "path": "sample/{name}",
            "connection": "testforfunctionapp_STORAGE"
        }, {
            "type": "blob",
            "name": "inputBlob",
            "path": "sample/{name}",
            "connection": "testforfunctionapp_STORAGE",
            "direction": "in"
        }
    ],
    "disabled": false
}
```

Could anyone please help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) to create a  blob trigger.

> i'm getting reference not found error

In your case, the `inputBlob` is a string type, you can't use `inputBlob.OpenRead()`. And there is no need additional bind `inputBlob`

Please have a try to use the following code. It works correctly on my side.

```
#r "System.IO"

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myBlob);
    string  oldContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    log.Info($"oldContent:{oldContent}");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. This is working. Could you please let me know whether we can trigger the function app when the file is uploaded into the sftp. I have checked the Integrate--> trigger--> External file. We have an option SFTP and I have created the sftp connection over there. But my function is not getting triggered when the file is uploaded into the sftp. Could you please help me on this ?

Comment: The trigger should work, you could refer to the [Azure Functions External File bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file). you also could create a new thread with detail description in new SO thread.

Comment: I have created the bidnings. But not sure what is the reason the function app is not triggering.  I have posted separate question with binding here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645933/can-we-trigger-the-function-app-when-the-file-is-uploaded-into-the-sftp

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the GetblobReference, which could be the cause of the issue:

```
 var blob = container.GetBlobReference("testblob.txt");

        blob.UploadText(new String('x', 5000000));

        var source = blob.OpenRead();
```

You can check the official doc for it **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblobreference?view=azure-dotnet)**

I'd also recommend checking the example in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911728/cloudblob-openread-is-not-reading-all-data)