# Can we trigger the function app when the file is uploaded into the sftp?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Can we trigger the function app when the file is uploaded into the sftp. I have checked the Integrate--> trigger--> External file. We have an option SFTP and I have created the sftp connection over there. But my function is not getting triggered when the file is uploaded into the sftp. Could you please help me on this ?

```
using System;

public static string Run(string inputFile, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info($"C# External trigger function processed file: " + name);
return inputFile;
}
```

Binding

```
{
"bindings": [
{
  "type": "apiHubFileTrigger",
  "name": "inputFile",
  "direction": "in",
  "path": "sample/{name}",
  "connection": "sftp_SFTP"
}

],
"disabled": false
}
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using logic app ?

Comment: Yes. Through logic app I'm able to trigger when the file uploaded. I want it to trigger through function app. Is it possible to trigger the function app when the file is uploaded into sftp.

Comment: dont know but why do you want to go with fnctions rather than logic apps ?

Comment: I want to learn whether we can do it through function app since we have option SFTP in the trigger. To learn more about azure function app.

Comment: my thought is: use logic app as much as you can (no code). if you can't do it wtih logic app, use functions

Comment: Ok. Can you let me know why the function is not triggering with above code. Since we have option SFTP in the trigger at integrate. The code supposed to be triggered when the file is uploaded into the SFTP. But it is not triggering. What will be the reason?

Comment: How are you deploying your function application?

Comment: Do you mean whether I'm using manual trigger or other trigger? If so, I'm using external file trigger. In the function --> Integrate -- Trigger --> External file

Answer (score 0):

If we create  External file trigger, we could know that External file trigger is still **Preview trigger**.

If Logic App is possible, **I recommand that you could use Logic App instead of Azure functon External file trigger currently**.

Based on my test, the trigger doesn't work with default template. Sometimes it works for me with following way.

**Note: The following ways just sometimes works for me**.

After create SFTP connection, we could get the SFTP  API connection in the resource group. For more information you could refer to the screenshot.

1.Edit the SFTP connection API(add the password)

[image]

2.Debug with Azure portal. Maybe get the error info **Binding data does not contain expected value 'name'**.

[image]

3.Change the bind name to other and change it back again.

4.Upload a new file to SFTP path and it will be triggered

[image]